# C++ struct definition with two names without :

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am deciphering someone else's c++ code which has the following struct definition (in an *.h file)

```
struct QD_API qd_real {
  double x[4];    /* The Components. */


  qd_real();
  qd_real(const char *s);
  qd_real(const dd_real &dd);
  qd_real(double d);
  qd_real(int i);
}
```

What does this code actually declare? I don't understand why there are two names after `struct`, not separated by `:`, thus this does not seem as an example of inheritance. I've looked around but did not find any help on such a weird usage.

Comment: `QD_API` is probably a macro: what is its definition?

Comment: As Andy said, QD_API is probably a macro that changes struct attributes. See [link]http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html[\link] to see some examples used in gcc compiler

Comment: You need to search for a preprocessor macro, it should look like "#define QD_API ...". In some IDEs you can simply right click QD_API and then "go to definition".

Comment: OK, thanks, got it. Currently it's defined as:

#ifndef QD_API

#define QD_API /**/

#endif

Comment: While this one evaluates to nothing, you would also this this type of syntax to wrap usage of `__declspec(dllexport)` & `__declspec(dllimport)` in a macro.

Answer (score 3):

I looked up the macro `QD_API` and it basically does nothing. It is there for decoration to indicate that the `struct` is a part of the `QD_API`.

```
#ifndef QD_API
#define QD_API /**/
#endif
```

See here: https://github.com/wilmerhenao/BFGS/blob/master/lib/qd/qd_config.h

Comment: Well, it doesn't do nothing. It ensures that `qd_config.h` has been included.

Comment: @PeterWood: Ok, fair enough, but it doesn't really ensure it because it wouldn't compile anyways.